# How does Judaism prove the existence of the life of the world to come?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, olam-haba-world-to-come

I have three questions:

- What is the basis for the Jewish belief in the World to Come?
- What human traits does Judaism consider reflect the possession of an eternal soul?
- What purpose(s) is/are served by the afterlife and the World to Come that cannot be served by this world in its present condition?

Comment: Your question was very unclear. I've edited it to what I *think* you meant. Please edit it further if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Do you have any reason to assume there is such a proof? Maybe Jews just believe it without proof but based on tradition.

Comment: And now it's very unclear again.

Comment: so please you edit it and clear it for me please ! please !

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi There are 14 question marks in your post, making it difficult for anyone else to decide how to edit it. Maybe you should just edit it to say, "What is the basis for the Jewish belief in the world to come?" (Wouldn't be surprised if that's a duplicate, though).

Comment: @Fred thanks a lot. please edit it . please.

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi I edited your question. If the new edit does not reflect your intention, please edit it again.

Comment: see the end of chapter 4 of shaar bitachon for why thetorah speaks only of reward/punishment in this world only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good place to start:
http://www.jewswithquestions.com/index.php?/topic/660-source-for-reward-and-punishment-in-the-next-world/
I asked Rabbi Shapiro of Basewater what is the source in scripture or otherwise for the world to come.

Comment: What does it say?  We're looking for answers rather than just links to answers; could you add a short summary at least?  Thanks.