# What did Jews really believe about the soul and life after death?

Tags: death, soul

As a Christian, I am very interested in learning what did *Jews* and *Judaism* teach about the *soul*, particularity, what happens to the *soul* when one *dies*?

Biblical scholar Bart D. Ehrman, is of the opinion that *most* of the, what we call, *Old Testament*, teaches that once one *dies*, the soul, which is the breath of life (see Genesis 2:7), also goes away.
He also notices the the Jewish word for *Sheol*, mostly means the *common grave*. And not some *Jewish* version of the *Greek* *Hades*.

However, while that looks plausible I also seems to me that the Christian new Testament, presents *Jews*, mostly noticeable, the *Pharisees*, as believing in a resurrection, and in *eternal life*?
This is why I used the word **really** in my question.

What did Jews really believe about the soul and life after death? I'm interested in the time before Jesus, from the foundation of Judaism, till and including the time of Jesus.

Comment: You might want to specify which period of time you're interested in knowing about

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65286/references-to-resurrection-and-the-afterlife-in-the-jewish-bible https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99269/what-jewish-denominations-believes-in-an-afterlife https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47936/what-is-the-orthodox-jewish-view-of-the-afterlife https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/life-after-death https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20619/is-it-true-that-jews-believed-in-sheol-before-the-belief-in-hereafter-entered-in

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23376/how-does-judaism-prove-the-existence-of-the-life-of-the-world-to-come https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7805/existence-of-heaven-and-hell https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/afterlife